# Bug with Marshal badge

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

I don't know exactly what happened, but in the last 7 days I have received twice the Marshal badge (which I had already earned in Apr 13) without raising more than 1500 helpful flags.
Now in my profile this gold badge is counted thrice instead of once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This bug was reported yesterday, and is now partially fixed. See: [Excavator and Marshal badges are being awarded over and over](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280023/excavator-and-marshal-badges-are-being-awarded-over-and-over) and [Extra number of gold badges appearing in profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280040/extra-number-of-gold-badges-appearing-in-profile?lq=1).

The consensus from the moderaters seems to be that this should be fixed by tomorrow. For example, [Oded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140505/oded) states ["This should get cleared up by a nightly job - lets see what it looks like tomorrow."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280040/extra-number-of-gold-badges-appearing-in-profile?lq=1#comment909107_280040)

Comment: Now seems to be fixed.